# Node spawn stdout undefined

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I have this code:

```
Printer.prototype.watch = function() {   
  var self = this;   var args = ["-P", this.name];
  var lpq = spawn('lpq', args);

  lpq.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
    (some irrelevant code)   
  });

  lpq.on("exit", function() {
    self.watch();   
  }); 
};
```

After some recursive calls, `spawn('lpq', args)` returns a object with `stdout=undefined`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **stderr** so you can see the error message.

```
lpq.stderr.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log("stderr------",data.toString());
  });
```

Comment: stderr is also undefined for me